# Styled Components with Typescript return type is any

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a component like:

```
class Foo extends React.Component<SkeletonProps, any> { ... }
```

When I use this with styled-components like:

```
const StyledFoo = styled(Foo)`height: 100px`
```

The type of StyledFoo is any (i.e no specific prop types), how can I make StyledFoo keep the `SkeletonProps` as its props?

Answer (score 0):

This pull request will fix this issue: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/50178/

Or you can run `npm ls hoist-non-react-statics` to find out 2.x version

Comment: Thank you for contributing and answering! It would be great to include the code from the pull request here in the post. also if you could explain how the solution works in detail, that would be fantastic. cheers

Comment: @Kirby You can see details in PR. I explained and provided a codesandbox

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Folks will be more likely to upvote your answer if the code is readable in plain text here at stackoverflow.com rather than having to click a link and then navigate to Files Changed. As well an explanation as to how the solution works is always highly valued.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the `3rd` version of `hoist-non-react-statics` worked for me.

```
npm add hoist-non-react-statics@3
```